# Select list value into Google Distance Matrix API - Javascript/HTML

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I want the distance matrix to accept values from 2 different drop down boxes. currently getting 'INVALID REQUEST'.

Here are the 2 drop down boxes;

```
 <select id="SelectDriver"> 
 <option value="{lat: 52.6, lng: 1}">DRIVER 1</option>
 <option value="{lat: 51.3, lng: -1.1}">DRIVER 2</option>
 <option value="{lat: 53.1, lng: -1.6}">DRIVER 3</option>
 </select>

 <select id="SelectDriver2"> 
 <option value="{lat: 52.6, lng: 1}">DRIVER 1</option>
 <option value="{lat: 51.3, lng: -1.1}">DRIVER 2</option>
 <option value="{lat: 53.1, lng: -1.6}">DRIVER 3</option>
 </select><br>
```

Here is the Distance Matrix code

```
document.getElementById('CheckDistance').onclick = function() {
document.getElementById('TestingMatrix').innerHTML =    
document.getElementById('SelectDriver').value;                                                                                                                                                                

    var origin1 = document.getElementById('SelectDriver').value;
    var origin2 = document.getElementById('SelectDriver').value;
    var destinationA = document.getElementById('SelectDriver2').value;
    var destinationB = document.getElementById('SelectDriver2').value;
```

The distance matrix DOES work if the var origin and var destination contains the (lat: x, lng: y} hardcoded in. The part where I change the innerHTML returns the lat long as expected: {lat: 52.6, lng: 1} - so can't why the request is different, it's exactly the same data. Can anyone advise why this is not working please?

The code works if i use

```
    var origin1 = {lat: 52.6, lng: 1};
    var origin2 = {lat: 52.6, lng: 1};
    var destinationA = {lat: 51.3, lng: -1.1};
    var destinationB = {lat: 51.3, lng: -1.1};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DistanceMatrix is expecting anonymous objects ([`LatLngLiteral`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/coordinates#LatLngLiteral) objects) as arguments, not strings that look like anonymous objects ("{lat: 52.6, lng: 1}").

If you make the `value` of the select a valid JSON string, you can call `JSON.parse` on it to get an anonymous object that will work with the `DistanceMatrix`:

```
<select id="SelectDriver"> 
 <option value='{"lat": 52.6, "lng": 1}'>DRIVER 1</option>
 <option value='{"lat": 51.3, "lng": -1.1}'>DRIVER 2</option>
 <option value='{"lat": 53.1, "lng": -1.6}'>DRIVER 3</option>
 </select>

<select id="SelectDriver2"> 
 <option value='{"lat": 52.6, "lng": 1}'>DRIVER 1</option>
 <option value='{"lat": 51.3, "lng": -1.1}'>DRIVER 2</option>
 <option value='{"lat": 53.1, "lng": -1.6}'>DRIVER 3</option>
 </select><br>
```

then it can be parsed to an anonymous object like this:

```
var origin1 = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('SelectDriver').value);
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/w4zoeha0/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  document.getElementById('TestingMatrix').innerHTML =
    document.getElementById('SelectDriver').value;

  var origin1 = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('SelectDriver').value);
  var destinationA = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('SelectDriver2').value);
  var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService;
  var request = {
    origins: [origin1],
    destinations: [destinationA],
    travelMode: 'DRIVING',
    unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
    avoidHighways: false,
    avoidTolls: false
  };
  console.log(JSON.stringify(request));
  service.getDistanceMatrix(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status !== 'OK') {
      alert('Error was: ' + status);
    } else {
      var originList = response.originAddresses;
      var destinationList = response.destinationAddresses;
      var outputDiv = document.getElementById('output');
      outputDiv.innerHTML = '';

      for (var i = 0; i < originList.length; i++) {
        var results = response.rows[i].elements;
        for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
          outputDiv.innerHTML += originList[i] + ' to ' + destinationList[j] +
            ': ' + results[j].distance.text + ' in ' +
            results[j].duration.text + '<br>';
        }
      }
    }
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<select id="SelectDriver">
  <option value='{"lat": 52.6, "lng": 1}' selected="selected">DRIVER 1</option>
  <option value='{"lat": 51.3, "lng": -1.1}'>DRIVER 2</option>
  <option value='{"lat": 53.1, "lng": -1.6}'>DRIVER 3</option>
</select>

<select id="SelectDriver2">
  <option value='{"lat": 52.6, "lng": 1}'>DRIVER 1</option>
  <option value='{"lat": 51.3, "lng": -1.1}' selected="selected">DRIVER 2</option>
  <option value='{"lat": 53.1, "lng": -1.6}'>DRIVER 3</option>
</select><br>
<input type="button" id="CheckDistance" value="Check distance" />
<div id="TestingMatrix"></div>
<div id="output"></div>
```